# Static initalization of a recusrsive data type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming, recursive-datastructures

I have the following code

```
#include <array>
#include <string_view>
#include <utility>

template<typename ... T>
struct node {};

template<typename head_t, typename ... tail_t>
struct node<head_t, tail_t ...>
{
  node(const head_t& head, const tail_t& ... tail)
    : head(head)
    , tail(tail...)
  {}

  head_t head;
  node<tail_t ... > tail;
};

template <typename... T>
node(T... t) -> node<T...>;
```

which I can initialize with

```
template <typename T>
using key = std::pair<std::string_view, T>;

int main()
{
  node n{key<int>{"a", 4}, key<int>{"b", 5}};
  return 0;
}
```

and compile with

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=gnu++17 -o test -c test.cpp
```

My question is: why does malloc get called in this scenario (detected with the `-Wl,--wrap=malloc` flag)?

Comment: I don't see the `malloc` being called [here](https://godbolt.org/z/tLAsyR)

Comment: Why are you certain it's your template code that's responsible for the malloc calls?  Please show your results/analysis.

Comment: hmm when I build a library then malloc gets called and when I build an executable then not...